# Application using SSO Cloud directory throwing Authorization error

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I have successfully created, configured and integrated SSO with my application at (https://console.bluemix.net). My project url is http://helloworldnew.mybluemix.net. I have created user **Manoj** while setting up SSO. 
Details are as follows:

- Username: Manoj
- Password: welcome2ibm11

Once user is logging in to the application, it keeps on giving an `"Authorization Failed"` message. 
Where and how to resolve the issue? 
The same thing happens with other users created while configuring SSO, like

- Username: Suruchi
- Password: welcome2ibm

I was able to access this project successfully using username Manoj one day ago, but now it's throwing the authorization error.

Comment: Can you share a little more information about your issue and some more error messages or logs?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the application you provided above is working when signing in with user id and password you provided.

Are you still seeing errors? If so please provide more detailed information including error you are seeing.

Thanks,

Alex.

Comment: It also worked for me using the credentials above. Maybe the OP's problem is a browser (session) related problem? Clearing the browser cache and reopening the browser might help. Often I simply close all windows and open a new "private" browser session so I'm sure cookies aren't being carried over from prior debug work.